# Laravel override a package event

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Is it possible to override a package provided event?

For example

Package "laravel/cashier-mollie" which is installed via composer into the vendor dir has an event laravel\cashier-mollie\src\Events\OrderPaymentFailed

What I want to do is update a specific field in my database when this event is fired.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be able to create a new Event that extends this one, such as `class MyCustomEvent extends OrderPaymentFailed`, then hook into the existing functionality to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own Listener for the event in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Laravel\Cashier\Events\OrderPaymentFailed;
use App\Listeners\OrderPaymentsFailedListener;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        OrderPaymentFailed::class => [
            // Your custom listener
            OrderPaymentsFailedListener::class,
        ],

    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```